# Tracking variable session $_SESSION

Tags: php, session-variables

I trying to see the sessions variables in a site,the site has 3 pages,2 with a form each and finally you get the last one,it based in the both previous form.

Is there a tool which record the data in the server while "travel"?I´m use f12 in chrome for see the cookies,but itsn`t show all.

Comment: https://xdebug.org 

Failing that, `var_dump($_SESSION)` on each page?

Comment: `record the data in the server while "travel"` So write the data into the `$_SESSION`!  And `cookies` are not equal to `$_SESSION`s. Only the SessionID is set in the cookie by PHP, if you need more data, use `set_cookie` http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php